# Using Vlookup inside array formula in Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have two sheets with relevant columns:

- Confirmed Cards

  - a. Email
  - b. Credits
- Purchase Credits.

  - a. Email
  - b. Rolling Total Credits

I'm hoping to populate "Credits" inside of "Confirmed Cards" with "Rolling Total Credits" from "Purchase Credits" by cross-referencing emails to show how many credits a user has.

I'm hoping to do this within an Array Formula, so as users are added to my database within confirmed cards, the amount of credits they own are automatically updated.

This is what I am currently using within "Confirmed Cards" to try to pull in the amount of credits the user has:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(A2:A,'Purchase Credits'!A2:F,5))
```

The formula correctly inputs the correct amount of credits for A2, the first user email, however, it inputs this value into every single row, regardless of email. For example, if `alex@gmail.com` has 100 credits, this amount shows for every single row within "Credits."

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a tutorial site or help/discussion forum***.  You have not provided any of the context required to understand what you are trying to do.  Put yourself in the place of someone who has no idea what your project is and explain at that level.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 0):

you will need 4th vlookup parameter. try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 'Purchase Credits'!A2:F, 5, 0)))
```